# How to use a field defined in outer class from inner class

Tags: c#, inner-classes

I've a class, called `myOuterClass` that has the following attributes:

```
public myOuterClass
{
   private object myObject;
   private List<myInnerClass> lists;


   .....
}
```

`myInnerClass`, as the name suggests, is a private inner class having some strings af field

```
public myOuterClass
{
     .......
     private myInnerClass
     {
         string _field1;
         string _field2;
     }
}
```

Now, in `myInnerClass`, I've to declare a method where I should use `_field1` and `_field2` and even `myObject`, the field defined in myOuterClass.
Is there a way to see `myObject` field even in `myInnerClass`? I would like, for design choice, maintain this structure and I would like not passing the reference as input like this:

```
 lists[i].myMethod(myObject);
```

because I think is not much elegant. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, because instance of inner class is not related in any way to instance of outer class - they exist independent of each other. So when you have some `myInnerClass` that does not mean there is some instance of `myOuterClass` to access.

Comment: `myInnerClass` instance knows nothing about other objects until you pass reference to those objects into `myInnerClass` instance. end of story

Comment: What you're looking for is Java's nested classes (the non-static form) - it doesn't exist in C#.

Comment: How are `myInnerClass` objects created? Can you not pass an instance of `myOuterClass` to it at that time?

Comment: Theoretically I can. It's what I'm doing. Simply, I don't like it. Think myOuterClass as a Father, myObject as its characteristic and myInnerClass as its child. I hoped to use a kind of visibility instead of using something like litteChildren.calculateAgeDifference(myObject). It seems that I must follow this way. Thank you so much :)